# File.AppendAllText causes access exception to be thrown when program run for the second time

Tags: c#, .net, file, logging, msdn

I have a log file that I delete and create every time my application is launched like so:

```
if (File.Exists(LogPath))
{
   File.Delete(LogPath);
   File.Create(LogPath);
}
```

And I'm writing in it using `File.AppendAllText` like so:

```
File.AppendAllText(LogPath, logMessage);
```

My issue is that when I run the program for the second time, the above call causes an exception to be thrown saying file can't be accessed

> "because it is being used by another process"

What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: Two instances of program are running at the same time?

Comment: is this the only code that affects the file specified by LogPath?  I would have expected an error with `File.Delete(LogPath);` before you even get to `File.AppendAllText(LogPath, logMessage);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's caused by `File.Create()`. Remove it and `File.AppendAllText` creates a new file if it doesn't exist.

**Note:**
`File.Create()` returns a `FileStream` value, if you do not dispose it, then it will cause an error when you want to access it.

Comment: And the reason your code works the first time, but not the second, is that you don't enter the clause where the `create()` call is made the first time.

Answer (score 2):

This is not because of `File.AppendAllText` but instead this line of code:

```
File.Create(LogPath);
```

As per [the documentation of File.Create(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Return Value
>   Type: System.IO.FileStream
>   A FileStream that provides read/write access to the file specified in path.

It **returns** an open `FileStream` object. You need to dispose of this object in order to close the stream and release the file. If you don't then this object will keep the file open until GC finalizes the object at some later indeterminate point in time.

Here's how to write this line of code, either one of the following two alternatives will work:

```
File.Create(LogPath).Dispose();
using (File.Create(LogPath)) { }
```

What happened is that the second time your program ran the file exists, so you deleted it and then recreated it, but the "recreated it" part kept the file open, so when it a short time later reached the `File.AppendAllText` method, the file was still open.

**Note**: If you **always** call `File.AppendAllText` you can simply just delete it, as `AppendAllText` will create the file if it doesn't already exist, as per [the documentation of File.AppendAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Opens a file, appends the specified string to the file, and then closes the file. **If the file does not exist, this method creates a file**, writes the specified string to the file, then closes the file.

*(my emphasis)*

Answer (score 0):

You would need to close the file after you create for further processing.

```
if (File.Exists(LogPath))
{
   File.Delete(LogPath);
   using(var handler = File.Create(LogPath))
   {

   }
}
```

Other way could be to use WriteAllText and you won't need to delete it everytime.

```
File.WriteAllText(LogPath, "contents");
```

Comment: `using (var handler = File.Create(LogPath)) {...}` is a better techique - do not close `IDisposable` (stream in the context) manually

Answer (score 0):

You, probably, mean

```
// clear the file (write an empty text to it) if it exists 
if (File.Exists(LogPath))
{
  File.WriteAllText(LogPath, "");
}    
...    
File.AppendAllText(LogPath, logMessage);
```

you can try *combining* clearing and writing in one call:

```
File.WriteAllText(LogPath, logMessage);
```

If the file exists, `WriteAllText` will clear it and write `logMessage`; if file doesn't exist, `WriteAllText` will create it and write `logMessage`.